# What can cause CSS to show as text on a webpage?

Tags: html, css, web

I'm running into a weird issue, where css code (pulled in from a .css file, NOT embedded in style tags) is showing as text on a page, and I'm not sure why. Do you know what could cause this? The css that is showing is:

```
background-color: #009eb4; color: white;
```

I checked the end of the file (Approx. 10,000 lines) and there's not CSS hanging off the end outside of a selector. I couldn't find any malformed css in the section that I edited either. The CSS shows up in the DOM as the first child of the body element.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML?

Comment: Have you tried ctrl+f ing that line of text in  your HTML? could be a stray copy and paste

Comment: You might load CSS from cache file, try hard refresh `(Ctrl + F5)`. Or, the css you expect to be loaded on specified element has been overridden by other styles and you can check this by inspecting your element.

Comment: Caroline Hermans, you're the best! It was in the html. I just started using Vim so I think I might have copied something between tabs accidentally. If you answer the question, I'll mark it as correct, thanks again!

Comment: @CarolineHermans Please add your comment as an answer so it can be selected as correct.

Comment: done, you're very welcome! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried ctrl+f ing that line of text in your HTML? could be a stray copy and paste :)